# ImageMagick - transparent background showing as black pixel in 'histogram:info:' output

Tags: imagemagick

My script is this… `convert test.png -alpha off -format %c histogram:info:`

Unfortunately, the output treats any transparent background in the PNG as a black pixel, meaning that the count of black pixels in my output is always higher than reality.

Does anyone know how to stop ImageMagick from treating transparent backgrounds as black pixels in the output of `histogram:info:`? Ideally, the transparent info should just be thrown away so as not to skew my results.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for those who are interested. This script works instead.

```
convert test.png -alpha remove -alpha off -format %c histogram:info:
```

The `-alpha remove` removes the alpha layer and then the `-alpha off` stops it from being outputted in `histogram:info:` entirely.